# Hapi does not return data attribute from Boom error

Tags: javascript, hapi.js

When replying with a Boom error from my Hapi route...

```
{
      method: 'PUT',
      path:'foo',
      handler: function (request, reply) {
        reply(Boom.badRequest('something', { stuff: 'and more' }));
      }
}
```

... I get the following response:

`{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"something"}`

It's missing the data object which provides the details of the error!  What's the deal?

Comment: Which version of hapi?

Comment: 7.2.0.  Posting an "answer" with what I found.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On the [Hapi documentation](http://hapijs.com/api#error-transformation) it references the `output.payload` property on the boom object, set by default to include `statusCode`, `error` and `message`.

I was able to output the details from the boom error by setting `.details` on this object:

```
{
      method: 'PUT',
      path:'foo',
      handler: function (request, reply) {
        var err = Boom.badRequest('something', { stuff: 'and more' });
        err.output.payload.details = err.data;
        reply(err);
      }
}
```

Not the most ideal thing in the world, but probably a safe default.

Comment: It does look as if this is the way you're supposed to do it.

Comment: this trick is working fine but If you are using typescript don't forget to make explicit the type `err:any` otherwise you will see the error "Property 'details' does not exist on type 'Payload'"

Answer (score 5):

I had the same question, and although I can't take the approach you've taken, there is the following in the [Boom FAQ](https://hapi.dev/module/boom/#faq):

> **Question** How do I include extra information in my responses? output.payload
>   is missing data, what gives?
>
> **Answer** There is a reason the values passed back in the response payloads
>   are pretty locked down. It's mostly for security and to not leak any
>   important information back to the client. This means you will need to
>   put in a little more effort to include extra information about your
>   custom error. Check out the ["Error transformation"](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/API.md#error-transformation) section in the hapi
>   documentation.

**Also:**

I found that (strangely), as the docs indicate (but not the example usage), passing a message to `badImplementation` is ignored, whereas passing a message to `notImplemented` - both are 5xx errors.

Docs for: [badImplementation](https://github.com/hapijs/boom#boombadimplementationmessage-data) vs [notImplemented](https://github.com/hapijs/boom#boomnotimplementedmessage-data)

Answer (score 0):

passing extra parameters is done via the data object, BUT, as stated in the code

```
/**
 * Custom error data with additional information specific to the error type
 */
data?: Data;
```

It is only specific information for specific error type

I found a workaround if you totally insist on adding the extra parameters

```
const err = Boom.badData('this is bad data message')
err.output.payload = { ...err.output.payload, attributes: { a: 'bb', c: 'ddd' } }
return err
```

this will yield the following payload:

```
{
  "statusCode": 422,
  "error": "Unprocessable Entity",
  "message": "this is bad data message",
  "attributes": {
    "a": "bb",
    "c": "ddd"
  }
}
```

you can write your own function that wraps this piece of code and use it