# Returning error object along with the hapijs boom object

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I'm trying to return the error object inside the response of a boom internal error object but it keeps omitting the error object.
I tried to follow the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463322/hapi-does-not-return-data-attribute-from-boom-error) but it didn't help.

```
function (request, reply) {

    options.healthCheck(function (err) {

        if (!err) {
            return reply('I\'m healthy!!!');
        }

        var boomErr = boom.internal('I don\'t feel so good', {
            err: err
        });
        boomErr.output.payload.details = err;
        return reply(boomErr);
    });
}
```

Here is the response:

```
{  
   "statusCode":500,
   "error":"Internal Server Error",
   "message":"An internal server error occurred",
   "details":{  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging into boom [docs](https://github.com/hapijs/boom), I found out that all 5xx errors hide the custom message and payload.
Switching to bad request error solved my issue.